# How can I differentiate between the different Emacs packages on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

What is the difference between each of the following.

- emacs22
- emacs22-nox
- emacs-snapshot
- emacs-snapshot-nox
- emacs21
- emacs21-nox
- emacs22-gtk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emacs snapshot is the CVS version of Emacs.  GTK is compiled with GTK support. NOX means compiled without X support.  vNN are the version numbers.

Note the latest stable release of GNU Emacs is 23.1.  emacs-snapshot is the closest to this.

Answer (score 1):

The number denotes which version of emacs - so v22, v21, etc.

NOX denotes that the release doesn't have X Window Support (I would imagine that it would thusly be CLI only).

Snapshot .. not sure, but it probably is a snapshot in between revisions of the software.

GTK is a library for building GUI's - this is a gui release of emacs.